# Show that $∃x[∀yLxy ⇔ ∃z¬Lxz]$ is a contradiction.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I know that to prove contradiction, I need to prove that $∃x[∀yLxy ⇔ ∃z¬Lxz]$ can derive $y$ & not $y.$

I got stuck at formulating the contradiction, because I don't know if $∀yLxy$ is the same as $∀zLxz$ intuitively. I think these two are different, but the contradiction I'm thinking about requires these two to be the same.

Comment: Since y in (∀y)Lxy and z in (∀z)Lxz are [bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) they are interchangeable, and these two expressions define the same predicate.

Comment: 1. $∀yLxy$  and $∀zLxz$ *are* logically equivalent.  2. To show that a given formula is unsatisfiable (i.e., a first-order contradiction) is to show that its negation is valid.

Comment: thank you so much!!!

Comment: $y$ is an object, not a proposition, so it doesn't make sense to refer to $y \land \lnot y$.  The only variable subject to being true or false is $L$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $$\exists x[\forall y Lxy \leftrightarrow \exists z \neg Lxz]$$ says that there is some object $x$ for which $$\forall y Lxy \leftrightarrow \exists z \neg Lxz$$ is true. So, if we call that object $a$, we get that

$$\forall y Lay \leftrightarrow \exists z \neg Laz$$

and by the quantifier negation law that means:

$$\forall y Lay \leftrightarrow \neg \forall z Laz$$

and now you see the contradiction: the left side says that $a$ stands in relation $L$ to every object, and yet the right side denies exactly that

(and yes, the fact that $y$ is used on the left side, and $z$ on the right side makes no difference: just as $\forall x P(x)$ and $\forall y P(y)$ say exactly the same thing .. variables are just 'dummy placeholders')

Now, not knowing how exactly (formal proof? truth tree? formal semantics? A more informal argument of the kind I just showed?) you are being asked to show that the statement is a contradiction, I can't help you any further, but hopefully you'll be able to take this line of reasoning and transform it into the kind of proof you are supposed to create.